# ReSpeaker Mic Array is not detected

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi3, microphone

The ReSpeaker Far-field Mic Array is not being detected in any machine I try it in. It is connected through USB. On my raspberry pi 3B there are no results from dmesg, lsusb, arecord, aplay for the mic. Plugging it into a windows machine gets nothing either, not found in devices at all. The mic itself does light up and is properly lighting the led's when there is sound nearby. Have tried different USB ports and different USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue.. i checked with 3 different cables but then realised that all those cables were just USB charging cables.. you need to use a usb data cable.

Answer (score 0):

The mic array failed, that was all. It did work before and was just sitting in storage as far as I know, but somewhere it must have been damaged somehow. Got a 2nd one and it works fine. I incorrectly assumed that because the LED's were still lighting up it must be working, nope, just hardware failure.